# How can I find the data from MongoDB for today's date?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am using the following code to find the data: :

```html
 module.exports.getdat = function(callback){
    console.log("database");
    const query = {sdate : new Date()}
    Time.find(query,callback);
  }
```

This is how my database look's like. Here i want to get data for which sdate is equal to today's date. [image: data]

How can I find the data from MongoDB for today's date?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use specific date range

Ranges can be specified using $gte and $lt in the same document portion:

```
db.time.find({sdate: {$gte: new Date("2018-08-03"),$lt: new Date("2018-08-04")}});
```